# Driving MOSFETs with the IR2104 for a buck converter doesn't give good results

Tags: mosfet, buck, mosfet-driver

I have been trying to create a buck converter with the [IR2104](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2104-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf) and two [TK2R4A08QM](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=70413&prodName=TK2R4A08QM) transistors, but it seems that the high side MOSFET can't cope with the load and gets too hot. I probed the gate voltages with my oscilloscope and they look like this:

[image]

Below is my schematic. I think I have low-enough gate resistors, and also reverse diodes.

[image]

The layout of the relevant part:

[image]

Is there something I am doing completely wrong here, or something that I can improve? Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Looks like you have some shoot trough. Also, can you show board layout?

Comment: I added it in the main question body!

Comment: Layout does not look too bad (gate traces and Vs return are somewhat long). I'd try increasing R1 and R2 first to get rid of the shoot trough. (The little kinks in the blue waveform where it crosses the yellow one - they should not cross).

Comment: So, in your experience, the gate rise time looks good? I will try increasing the resistors, and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: The gate turn-off is slow. The symbol for D2 and D3 indicates a schottkey diode. Is it really a schottkey diode?

Comment: Consider a stronger gate driver e.g. IRS2184.  Also, where is the nearest capacitor between VCC/GND?

Comment: @Mattman944 They are schottkey diodes [SS310L](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Taiwan%20Semi%20PDFs/SS34L-SS310L_C2103.pdf)

Comment: @TimWilliams The nearest is the one partially shown in the PCB. It's an electrolytic 47uF. I will look into IRS2184, thanks!

Comment: @Unimportant I increased the R1 and R2 to 50Ω and now the graph looks like this: [50Ohms](https://pasteboard.co/l6Y5UgXH1H1x.png). Maybe that shoot through is because of my Q2 gate trace going over the VS trace at the bottom layer?

Comment: Are you sure of the value for C1 bootstrap cap? This should be at least 10 times greater than the gate capacitance of the high-side FET, but not too high. https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua887/slua887.pdf?ts=1661417777497&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MOSFETs you are driving have an input capacitance of 13 nF. The switching time characteristics of the IR2104 assume a 1 nF load. This might seriously affect rise and fall times causing excessive power dissipation in both MOSFETs. You need a stronger MOSFET driver in my opinion.

> *@Andyaka You are right! I swapped them out for some FQP50N06 I had
> laying around, and now it works like a charm! Thank you for noticing
> this!*